# How to prove $ A^c \cup B \subseteq (A - B)^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

## My try:

Suppose $x \in A^c \cup B$. We know $x \in  A^c$ or $x \in B$, which is the same as $x \notin A$ or $x \in B$.

From there I don't how to mais the synthesis of the other set.

Comment: Note that $(A-B) = \{x~:~x\in A~\wedge~x\notin B\}$ so $(A-B)^c = \{x~:~x\notin A~\vee x\in B\}$ which is exactly what you got to earlier.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on — showing that $A^c\subseteq(A-B)^c$ or showing that $B\subseteq(A-B)^c$?

Comment: Both proves are not clean to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a strict logic argument:

$ x \notin A $ or $x \in B$

$ \iff \sim ( \sim ( x \notin A $ or $x \in B))$

$ \iff \sim ( x \in A $ and $x \notin B)$

$\iff \sim (x \in A \setminus B )$

$\iff x \in (A \setminus B )^{c}$

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Supose that $x\notin (A-B)^c$, therefore $x\in A- B$, contradiction!